# User Defined Function transforming Python Pandas Dataframe Not Working

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Apparently I don't understand how return statements in user-defined functions work. The code works when I remove the statements out of the function. I think the problem is with the return statement.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"index_id": range(101, 131),
    'company': ['Opera', 'Opera', 'Opera', 'Opera', 'Opera', 'Opera',
    'Firefox', 'Firefox', 'Firefox', 'Firefox', 'Firefox', 'Firefox',
    'Safari', 'Safari', 'Safari', 'Safari', 'Safari', 'Safari',
    'Brave', 'Brave', 'Brave', 'Brave', 'Brave', 'Brave',
    'Chrome', 'Chrome', 'Chrome', 'Chrome', 'Chrome', 'Chrome'],
    "rating": [4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3,
    4, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5,
    1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2,
    1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5,
    5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def AggRankBinRenameJoin (df_unaggdf):
    #aggregating the unaggregated df
    df_agg = df_unaggdf.groupby(['company']).agg({'rating':['std', 'mean']})
    df_agg.columns = ['rating_std', 'rating_mean']
    print(df_agg)
    df_rank = df_agg.rank(ascending = 0, method = 'dense').add_prefix('rank_')
    print(df_rank)
    bin_labels = ['Diamond', 'Platinum', 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze']
    #bin_labels_reverse = ['Bronze', 'Silver', 'Gold', 'Platinum', 'Diamond']
    df_bin= df_rank.apply(lambda x:pd.qcut(x, q=[0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1], labels=bin_labels))
    print(df_bin)
    output = df_agg.join(df_rank).join(df_bin.add_prefix('bin_'))
    print(output)
    df_unaggdf = output.copy(deep = True)
    return df_unaggdf

AggRankBinRenameJoin(df)
```

Comment: what does `not working` mean? Any errors or semantic expectation? Explain.

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify the dataframe/and or variables you would like to return.

As in:

```
def AggRankBinRenameJoin (df_unaggdf):
    #aggregating the unaggregated df
    df_agg = df_unaggdf.groupby(['company']).agg({'rating':['std', 'mean']})
    df_agg.columns = ['rating_std', 'rating_mean']
    print(df_agg)
    df_rank = df_agg.rank(ascending = 0, method = 'dense').add_prefix('rank_')
    print(df_rank)
    bin_labels = ['Diamond', 'Platinum', 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze']
    #bin_labels_reverse = ['Bronze', 'Silver', 'Gold', 'Platinum', 'Diamond']
    df_bin= df_rank.apply(lambda x:pd.qcut(x, q=[0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1], labels=bin_labels))
    print(df_bin)
    output = df_agg.join(df_rank).join(df_bin.add_prefix('bin_'))
    print(output)
    df_unaggdf = output.copy(deep = True)
    return df_unaggdf
```

If you want to transform the original df using the function specify

`df=AggRankBinRenameJoin(df)`

Note I didn't review this for any other potential errors. If there are any, it would be helpful if you edit your question to have the error message shown.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Needed to set the function AggRankBinRenameJoin (which returns a dataframe) equal to a variable, so the variable would equal that returned dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"index_id": range(101, 131),
    'company': ['Opera', 'Opera', 'Opera', 'Opera', 'Opera', 'Opera',
    'Firefox', 'Firefox', 'Firefox', 'Firefox', 'Firefox', 'Firefox',
    'Safari', 'Safari', 'Safari', 'Safari', 'Safari', 'Safari',
    'Brave', 'Brave', 'Brave', 'Brave', 'Brave', 'Brave',
    'Chrome', 'Chrome', 'Chrome', 'Chrome', 'Chrome', 'Chrome'],
    "rating": [4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3,
    4, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5,
    1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2,
    1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5,
    5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def AggRankBinRenameJoin (df_unaggdf):
    #aggregating the unaggregated df
    df_agg = df_unaggdf.groupby(['company']).agg({'rating':['std', 'mean']})
    df_agg.columns = ['rating_std', 'rating_mean']
    print(df_agg)
    df_rank = df_agg.rank(ascending = 0, method = 'dense').add_prefix('rank_')
    print(df_rank)
    bin_labels = ['Diamond', 'Platinum', 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze']
    #bin_labels_reverse = ['Bronze', 'Silver', 'Gold', 'Platinum', 'Diamond']
    df_bin= df_rank.apply(lambda x:pd.qcut(x, q=[0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1], labels=bin_labels))
    print(df_bin)
    output = df_agg.join(df_rank).join(df_bin.add_prefix('bin_'))
    print(output)
    df_unaggdf = output.copy(deep = True)
    return df_unaggdf

df1 = AggRankBinRenameJoin(df)
```